# is PP ‘out’ an adjunct or a complement of V ‘get’ in ‘get out’

Tags: syntax, english, x-bar-theory

As the title shows, in a VP ‘get out’, is PP ‘out’ an adjunct of VP ‘get’, or a complement of V ‘get’?

Comment: It depends on the context. _Get out the binoculars_ is not the same as _Get out of here_.

Comment: @jlawler for example “I stop the car and get out.”

Comment: for this second language speaker it's a univerbation, *gettout*, quoting Elaine from Seinfeld. In German it would really be a univerbation *raus hier!*, supposedly contracted from the PP *her-aus*, but I doubt that to the point that I want to derive the *r-* from elsewhere (from a laryngeal, or simply the same morpheme as in *he-re*, that requires it to have been morphemic before becoming an inflectional suffix, cp Dutch *er*). It's difficult to see however that should pertain to this question, if *get* were a Middle Engl. loan from Norse, in case it acquired the sense "become, go" only later

Comment: In the sentence "Get out", "out" is complement of "get". It must be a complement since it is obligatory for this sense of "get", which means to leave somewhere like a car or house. Obligatory items are always complements.

Comment: So, by this definition of _complement_, all the particles in phrasal verbs are complements?

Comment: If a dependent is obligatory that is sufficient to make it a complement.

Comment: This link could be helpful (consider also references therein): http://naosite.lb.nagasaki-u.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/10069/15278/1/kyoyoJ31_02_03_t.pdf

Comment: I very much dislike the term 'phrasal verb'. It's misleading since it implies that in, say, "They fell out", fell out" is a verb, which it isn't. It's just "fell" that is a verb. "Out" is a preposition.

Comment: @BillJ - "fell out" is a 'prepositional verb' rather than a 'phrasal verb', because the particle cannot move ("*They fell the window out").  You are right that 'out' in "get out" is a complement (an object or subject complement depending ...).

Comment: @amI Or a verbal idiom. I used "fall out" as example because grammar websites give it as phrasal verb.